# Calculate $\sum_{i=1}^n\sin(\frac{\pi\ i}{2n})$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\sin(\frac{\pi\ i-\pi}{2n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Need to calculate the following:$\sum_{i=1}^n\sin(\frac{\pi\ i}{2n})$, $\sum_{i=1}^n\sin(\frac{\pi\ i-\pi}{2n})$.

I am sorry that this is short, but I don't know how to even begin. I have tried to look for trigonometric identities, but haven't seen something that fits in these cases. I will be glad for some help. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: For real $x$, $\sin(x)=\Im \exp(ix)$

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in a more general case of finding $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx)$$
The hint for this one would be
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(kx) = \Im\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (e^{ix})^k\right)$$
where $i^2 = -1$.

---

> Here go the calculations:
> $$\color{red}{\Im}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (e^{ix})^k\right)$$
> Let us calculate the inner sum.
> $$\begin{align}
> \sum_{k=1}^n (e^{ix})^k 
> &= e^{ix} + e^{2ix} + \dots + e^{nix} \\
> &= \frac{e^{ix}(1-e^{nix})}{1-e^{ix}} \\
> &= \frac{(\cos x + i\sin x)(1-\cos x - i \sin x)}{1 - \cos x - i \sin x} \\
> \end{align}$$
> which gives the imaginary part
> $${\Im}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (e^{ix})^k\right) = \frac{\sin\frac{nx}{2}\sin\frac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}$$

---

> Another way **without** complex numbers is making this a telescoping sum using the identity
> $$\sin(kx)\sin(x/2) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left((k-1/2)x\right)-\cos\left((k+1/2)x\right)\right)$$

---

While finding $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(a+kb)$$
remember that $\sin(a+kb) = \sin(a)\cos(kb) + \cos(a)\sin(kb)$. Then the sum becomes
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(a+kb) &= \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\sin(a)\cos(kb) + \cos(a)\sin(kb)\right] \\&= \sin(a)\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kb) + \cos(a)\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(kb)\end{align}$$
Now you can use the result from the first part.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many, many times: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/17966?lq=1

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen this formula.

Comment: wait what is this j multiplied by the sigma?

Comment: @MartinR I added more information. Hopefully, most of those answers do not include this.

Comment: @aasc232 $\Im$ stands for the *imaginary part*. And the formula itself is called the Euler's identity.

Comment: I can't understand what is this 'j', can you provide a full answer?

Comment: I honestly doubt that anything can be added to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969 (or the 200 other Q&As that already link to it).

Comment: @MartinR Yes, sorry. I didn't see this one. Ok, then I will vote for closing this.

Comment: @aasc232 Forget about $\Im$ for a moment. Calculate the sum that is inside first which is basically a geometrical progression. Then find the imaginary part of the result.

Comment: But I don't know to do this.  I am afraid that I cannot calculate in this way, because I didn't learn this formula.

Comment: @aasc232 Have you looked through the links provided by Martin R?

Comment: yes, it could be related to my question. However, it is something that I don't familiar with. Therefore, I will be glad for a full answer.

Comment: @aasc232 Check [this](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Knapp200941575.pdf) out.

Comment: Still, cannot see how this solves my question.

Comment: @aasc232 See the edit. I added a hint for solving without complex numbers.